# Wrong crdate in fe_user of TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

I have a frontend user registration on a TYPO3 site (with Femanager).
Now i noticed that some of my users (nearly 3%) have a completely wrong crdate in the database.
The date is not between the id before/after and it's months in the future.

I thought the crdates where auto-generated via TYPO3 or even MySQL (but i'm not quite sure).

I've no clue where this problem could be located.
Could this be a server problem? But the users are not created at the same day. There are correct values between them.

Comment: the crdate is automatically set by typo3. If you did not import some users with an external script then it must be a server problem. It could occur if the server time was wrong - may be a sync problem of the server time?

Comment: Hm, ok. I'll try to verify this by the logs/support. Thank you

Comment: The Server Logs do not have this problem. Everything is after the Item before. I've looked for the items of the wrong User registration. Maybe the Database Server is the problem. But i don't know how to debug this.

Comment: The crdate is still wrong on those systems. But the problem does not always occur on creation. Maybe it comes from the profile-edit page (femanager)